# Razorpage: Convert js param into c# param

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I am doing this:

```
function AddSubSub(idOfSubsub) {

                    $('#mainForm').dirtyForms('setClean');
                    var mainForm = document.getElementById('mainForm');
                    mainForm.action = '@Url.Action("AddSubSub", "GlobalTagging", new { idOfSubsub = 3})';
                    mainForm.submit();
                }
```

This will call my controller function and give it the id of 3. But i want it to give me the id of "idOfSubsub" from the input var in the function. However, I have no access to that as I go with @Url which starts a c# query.

How can I pass my variable through?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    mainForm.action = `@Url.Action("AddSubSub", "GlobalTagging", new { idOfSubsub = ${idOfSubsub}})`;
```

Comment: Thank you. This however gave me: unexpected symbol: $

Comment: Did you try slash quote(as in my code), not straight quote(as in your code) ? :)

Comment: yeah, i copied your exact line...